# How to speed up RANK() in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Building a tool in Excel and as part of the exercise I need to identify the top 50 securities based on market cap.

This is an easy enough thing to do using RANK(), but I've got a universe of over 10,000 and processing of an otherwise lightening quick workbook gets sluggish once I add the rank over these 10,000 entries.

I realize the sluggishness is due at least in part to Excel needing to sort the entries in order to rank them so I'm wondering if some kind of index on the values to be ranked could speed things up?  Is there a better way to do this, either via an Excel function(s) that I'm unfamiliar with or using a some other approach to speed things up?

Comment: how are you using the `RANK` formula? did you copy a `RANK` for the 50 first ones? maybe we could find a good UDF solution because vba could sort the array and then display the value (and i'm sure Issun would love to design one :))? Could you tell us how you are using the results? Do you mind if we give the results in a single cell you would then have to split?

Comment: How am I using it subsequently or how am I implementing the RANK()? 

Regarding point 1, I'm using the rank as an 'ID' to subsequently pull the top 50 into a different sheet.

Regarding implementation, it's just RANK(individual market cap, market cap array).

Comment: I have some ideas for a VBA solution but just want to clarify a few things: I the market cap data just a floating point number? What do you want to do in off cases where the 50th and 51st rankness of the same value? Finally, do you need to add a row on the new sheet to write the rank?

Comment: Also is the main intention to generate the sheet of the top 50 or have a persistent function that identifies the rank for each item in your list at any given time?

Comment: (1)  Yes, the market cap is a floating point number.  

(2)  Assume ties aren't an issue--considering the likelihood that two companies have market cap of exactly 25,205,303M is pretty slim.  

(3)  The rank column on the subsequent worksheet isn't critical, but if possible, I'd like it. 

(4)  Well, the way I have it set up now, I use the 'rank' column as an ID to pull the top 50 into a different worksheet.  So, let's say populate a separate worksheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could sort the values the way you want and then use a function like ROW() to simply assign the rank sequentially (although you might need to pay do something special to break "ties").

If you don't want to sort the values, it depends on what you need...

**Case 1** -- You don't actually need the rank, but only need to identify the top 50 values.

Suppose your values are in cells A1:A10000.

In another cell, say E1, enter a formula that calculates the "cutoff" for the top 50 values like this `=PERCENTILE($A$1:$A$10000,50/COUNT($A$1:$A$10000))`.

In cell B1, enter a formula that returns the value in A1 if it is below the "cutoff", or an empty string otherwise like this `=IF(A1<=$E$1,A1,"")`.

Copy this formula down to cells B2 through B10000.

The rows with top 50 values in column A will have non-blank values in column B.

There may be more than 50 such rows if there are ties.

**Case 2** -- You need the rank, but only for the top 50 values.

Follow the instructions for Case 1, then, in cell C1, enter a formula that calculates the rank for the non-blank values in column B like this `=IF(B1="","",RANK(B1,$B$1:$B$10000))`.

Copy this formula down to cells C2 through C10000.

The rows with top 50 values in column A will be ranked in column C.

Again, there may be more than 50 such rows if there are ties.  There will also be gaps in the rank values if there are ties.

**Case 3** -- You need the rank for all 10000 values.

Use RANK like you are now.

Comment: Interesting ideas, I appreciate your response.


For my purposes, your PERCENTILE/RANK suggestion ought to work.  I'm going to keep this open a little while longer to see if there are any other ideas though.

Comment: So you just need the rows for the top 50 paste into another sheet? And for the column you are using to base the ranking on, what is the data type? Can you give 1 example?

Comment: If you are copying the top 50 to another sheet anyway, a fast and simple solution might be to simply sort the data first as I initially suggested.

Comment: Issun: Data type of the ranked column is float/decimal and yes, I need the top 50/100/etc. (this is a variable specified elsewhere) collected in a separate worksheet.  I'm not sure why you'd need to resort to VBA for this though as the only hang-up is around the speed of RANK.    

Brian:  I'm not copying/pasting anything.  As is, I use the 'rank' column as an ID and just use it via an INDEX/MATCH to pull the top 50 entries into the adjacent worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to generate a list of the Top 50 is to utilize the auto-filter in Excel, which is faster than any loop you can write.

Here's an example of how to do it assuming:

- Row 1 is a header column
- In the example, column G is the row with the Market Cap

How it works: This is a ducttape solution, but works really well.

1. Copies the current sheet to a new sheet called "Top 50"
2. Applies auto-filter and filters it in descending order (highest numbers first)
3. Deletes all rows after the 50th entry
4. Select A1 just for to make it pleasing to the eyes :)

There are a ton of ways to improve this code such as:

- Sloopy assumptions on where end of column is
- Add a column for rank and plug in 1 through 50

I think this code is a good place to start, though. Adjust the column G to the column with your data and give it a try!

```
Sub FilterbyDescending()
' filter row G in desceneding order
Dim filter As Range
Set filter = Range("A1:G100000")
    filter.Sort Key1:=Range("G2:G1000000"), _
    Order1:=xlDescending, _
    Header:=xlYes, _
    Ordercustom:=1, _
    MatchCase:=False, _
    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
End Sub

Sub CreateBackup()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Create the Top 50 sheet, paste current sheet to it
Dim top50sheet As Variant
Application.ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Application.Worksheets.Count)
Set top50sheet = Application.ActiveSheet
top50sheet.Name = "Top 50"

Dim rowCount As Long
Dim columCount As Long

Call FilterbyDescending
' Time to delete everything after the top 50
Range("A52").CurrentRegion.Select
rowCount = Selection.Rows.Count
columnCount = Selection.Columns.Count
Range(Cells(52, 1), Cells((rowCount), columnCount)).Delete

Cells(1, 1).Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```